# django reverse url hitting same url

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a base URL file that includes all apps URL files, and what I am trying to do is on click of `Generate PDF Button`, I want to hit an `APIView / view-function` passing a variable along as parameter via `get` method without encoding.
**HTML:**

```
<form onsubmit="{% url 'api-product:invoice-pdf-get' %}?R={{ variable }}">
<input type="submit" value="Generate PDF">
</form>
```

**Base URL**

```
path('api/product/', include(('store.urls', 'store'), namespace='api-product')),
path('invoice/', InvoiceUrl.as_view(), name='print-invoice'),
```

**App URL:**

```
path('invoice-pdf-get/', invoice.InvoiceToPdf.as_view(), name='invoice-pdf-get'),
```

**On Click URL Generated:** (Which is current, except with parameter)

```
http://localhost:8000/invoice/?
```

[image: HTML INSPECT]

Can't understand why am I getting the same URL though when I inspect the HTML I see the URL included there, but **without** `localhost:8000`.
There are several answers related to reverse URL on `StackOverflow`, none helped.
Also I am not having any java script etc included, only bootstrap and a simple custom CSS. Have just a plain table.
If I just **open the HTML from windows** file directory, **and click button** I get:

```
http://localhost:63342/pos2all/templates/pogo-invoice.html?
```

**UPDATED:**
Now the parameter is not passed though still visible in HTML inspect, same way as above picture.
[image]

**The API Looks Like:**

```
class InvoiceToPdf(APIView):
    """
    This API is used to get the Invoice and return pdf of invoice
    using rest_framework Response and  premission_classes
    """
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):
        return Response("hi")
```

Comment: What value are you expecting to be passed? You don't have any fields in your form, there are no values to pass

Comment: in url patter it shows  `/?R=` I am expecting to get it as `request.GET.get['R']`, won't it be passed as I was looking at stackoverflow for how to pass parameters via get, they suggested this @DanielRoseman

Comment: basically I want to pass a parameter via get method to the api,

Comment: probably there is something wrong with pattern of `invoice-pdf-get`

Comment: If I change patter to `invoice-pdf-get/?R=`, it says page not found,

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman I did it with form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the form `action` attribute instead of `onsubmit`.

```
<form action="{% url 'api-product:invoice-pdf-get' %}">
```

The `action` attribute is the url you want to form to be submitted to. But the form will add the data from the inputs as query parameters when you submit a form with the GET method, so you can't have a query string in the action url.

To pass query parameters with a form submission, use form inputs. You can use `hidden` fields for data that the user is not supposed to edit.

```
<form action="{% url 'api-product:invoice-pdf-get' %}" >
  <input type="hidden" name="R"  value="{{ variable }}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Generate PDF" />
</form>
```

The default method for form submission is `GET`, but you can add the method explicitly to make this more clear.

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'api-product:invoice-pdf-get' %}">
```

Comment: this is the url I am getting without the parameter, the parameter is just a invoice_id